# Compare a list of dictionaries with logic and action each one

Tags: python

There is a lot of related questions on here but none I can decipher to meet my criteria. So what I'm trying to do is check if an active schedule is is in the scheduled_sites and if it is leave it, if it is not then add it to the scheduled_sites with the dashboard set to false

Sample data:

```
>>> scheduled_sites
[{'id': 128, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}, {'id': 61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}]
>>> active_schedules
[{'id': 1, 'scheduled_dashboard': True},{'id': 61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}]
```

Desired outcome:

```
[{'id': 128, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}, {'id': 61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}, {'id': 1, 'scheduled_dashboard': False}]
```

I feel like I'm close with the below but am getting errors or blanks...

```
>>> if any(a["id"] == s["id"] for s in scheduled_sites for a in active_schedules):
...     s
...
>>> if any(a["id"] == s["id"] for s in scheduled_sites for a in active_schedules):
...     a
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: s and a are only defined inside the generator comprehension of `any(...)` - you do not have access from the outside. Use normal loops instead.#

Comment: how would I do this?

Comment: did you write those generators? just turn them back into the loops they represent, and add a break with the if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` and `a` are only defined inside the generator comprehension of `any(...)` - you do not have access from the outside.

Use normal loops/sets/dicts instead:

```
import copy

scheduled_sites  = [{'id': 128, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}, 
                    {'id':  61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}]
active_schedules = [{'id':   1, 'scheduled_dashboard': True},
                    {'id':  61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}]


# get missing keys
scheduled = set( (k["id"] for k in scheduled_sites) )
active = set( (k["id"] for k in active_schedules) )

# for lots of schedules it is cheaper to only iterate those that are missing
not_scheduled = active-scheduled

for not_in in not_scheduled:
    for d in active_schedules:
        if d["id"] == not_in:
            # copy the dict you need to decouple this reference from the other one
            scheduled_sites.append(copy.deepcopy(d))
            scheduled_sites[-1]["scheduled_dashboard"] = False

print(scheduled_sites)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 128, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}, 
 {'id': 61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True},
 {'id': 1, 'scheduled_dashboard': False}]
```

Comment: thank you. This is great and the explanations help a lot too!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
for active in active_schedules:
    if not any(active == scheduled for scheduled in scheduled_sites):
        new_site = {
            'id': active['id'],
            'scheduled_dashboard': False,
        }
        scheduled_sites.append(new_site)
```

Answer (score 0):

The comprehension syntax only keeps the variables in scope for the call to `any`. In order to preserve the variables you need to define the loop explicitly, or store the results while inside of the scope of the comprehension.

```
for a in active_schedules:
     for s in scheduled_sites:
         if a['id'] == s['id']:
             print("a: {}, a: {}".format(a, s))
```

Outputs:

`a: {'id': 61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}, a: {'id': 61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}`

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop here. Just go through your active ones to see if it's scheduled. If not, add it to your list of scheduled:

```
scheduled_sites = [{'id': 128, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}, {'id': 61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}]
active_schedules = [{'id': 1, 'scheduled_dashboard': True},{'id': 61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}]

scheduled_ids = set(x['id'] for x in scheduled_sites)
for active in active_schedules:
    if active['id'] not in scheduled_ids:
        scheduled_sites.append(active)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 128, 'scheduled_dashboard': True},
 {'id': 61, 'scheduled_dashboard': True},
 {'id': 1, 'scheduled_dashboard': True}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this,

**Code**

```
    for a in active_schedules:
        if a not in scheduled_sites:
            scheduled_sites.append(a)
    print (scheduled_sites)
```